# Example of delegation in object-oriented programming: Clarification needed

Tags: oop, delegation

Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(programming):

```
class A {
  void foo() {
    // "this" also known under the names "current", "me" and "self" in other languages
    this.bar();
  }

  void bar() {
    print("a.bar");
  }
};

class B {
  private delegate A a; // delegation link

  public B(A a) {
    this.a = a;
  }

  void foo() {
    a.foo(); // call foo() on the a-instance
  }

  void bar() {
    print("b.bar");
  }
};

a = new A();
b = new B(a); // establish delegation between two objects
```

> Calling `b.foo()` will result in `b.bar` being printed, since `this`
>   refers to the original receiver object, `b`, within the context of
>   `a`.

Can someone clarify the explanation immediately above? I think I understand the basic principle, but I'm still unsure as to why it would call the `foo()` method from class `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `b.foo()` calls `this.a.foo()`

Because `b.a` is declared `delegated`, `this.a.foo()` is called in the context of `b`

2. `a.foo()` calls `this.bar()`

Because `a.foo()` is called in the context of `b`, `this` keyword inside `a.foo()` references `b`, not `a`. Thus, `this.bar()` references `b.bar()`.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia article ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(programming) ) is talking about a feature named "delegation" which is something I haven't experienced.

Quote #1 from the wikipedia article you referenced:
"**Calling b.foo() will result in b.bar being printed, since this refers to the original receiver object, b, within the context of a.**"

They're basically overriding "this" in class A so that it happens to point to an instance of Class B.  I suspect the override is temporary and could change from invocation to invocation against Class A's methods.  Good luck figuring out what a given instance of class A is going to do if it that same instance is serving as a "delegate" for Class B, C, and D all with varying implementations of "bar()".

I would not want to be the programmer responsible writing Class A if "this" was going to be some arbitrary class B or (class C ... class Z) at runtime; it feels like a research topic that was good for a thesis but maybe not so helpful for work-a-day programming.  I'd be interested to read of any examples the stackexchange crowd could offer where they found this kind of behavior helpful.

Quote #2 from the wikipedia article you referenced:
"**Programming languages in general *do not support this unusual form of delegation* as a language concept, but there are a few exceptions [citation needed]**"

I agree with [citation needed], I would love to hear of any languages that actually support this.

### sample Java output

Note that Java doesn't work at all the way the Wikipedia article describes.
It is probably pointless to use the word "delegate" in the source code because it is misleading, at least in the sense of the wikipedia article concept.  But I left it in to make it easier to compare the wikipedia sample "code" with the following.

```
$ java B
> B(), adding delegateA@2a139a55
< B()
----- a.foo() ---
> A.foo(), calling this.bar()
A.bar(): hello from a.bar
< A.foo(), back from this.bar()
----- a.bar() ---
A.bar(): hello from a.bar
----- b.foo() ---
> B.foo(), calling a.foo()
> A.foo(), calling this.bar()
A.bar(): hello from a.bar
< A.foo(), back from this.bar()
< B.foo(), back from  a.foo()
----- b.bar() ---
B.bar(): hello from b.bar
$
```

Now... as a thought experiment, IF java implemented that kind of 'delegation' the last part of the output would look (I think) more like this:

```
//This isn't actual output from java at all,
//I just edited this trying to make it look like
//what I think the wikipedia-style "delegation" would do.
----- b.foo() ---
> B.foo(), calling a.foo()
> A.foo(), calling this.bar()
B.bar(): hello from b.bar  // Big difference here vs. actual java output above.
< A.foo(), back from this.bar()
< B.foo(), back from  a.foo()
----- b.bar() ---
B.bar(): hello from b.bar
$
```

### class A

```
class A {
  void foo() {
    System.out.println("> A.foo(), calling this.bar()");
    this.bar();
    System.out.println("< A.foo(), back from this.bar()");
  }

  void bar() {
    System.out.println("A.bar(): hello from a.bar");
  }
}
```

### class B

```
class B {
  // private delegate A a; // delegation link
  // above line doesn't compile in Java, "delegate" not a key word.
  private A a; // delegation link, without "delegate" key word.

  public B(A a) {
    System.out.println("> B(), adding delegate"+a+"");
    this.a = a;
    System.out.println("< B()" );
  }

  void foo() {
    System.out.println("> B.foo(), calling a.foo()");
    a.foo(); // call foo() on the a-instance
    System.out.println("< B.foo(), back from  a.foo()");
  }

  void bar() {
    System.out.println("B.bar(): hello from b.bar");
  }

   public static void main( String args[] ) {
      A a = new A();
      B b = new B(a);
      System.out.println("----- a.foo() ---");
      a.foo();
      System.out.println("----- a.bar() ---");
      a.bar();
      System.out.println("----- b.foo() ---");
      b.foo();
      System.out.println("----- b.bar() ---");
      b.bar();
   }
}
```